# Proper data model for a 2D Tilemap (C++, Qt)

Tags: c++, image, qt, datamodel

I made a small 2D level editor where you can create 2D tile based maps..however, the performance inside my application is really really bad. I am currently thinking to start all over again.

The Problem is, I currently use QGraphicsItem's to represent a single tile inside a QGraphicsScene. A tile has some properties..including an image. When a map is created, I create an item for each tile which draws an image for each tile..which basically is a lot of graphicitems and it slows down the whole application. This is the function that populates a map once it is created :

```
    for(int i=0;i<map->m_rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<map->m_cols;j++)
        {
            Tile* thetile=map->getAt(i,j);
            if(thetile)
            {
                if(map->getType()==twoditor::RECTANGLETILE)
                {
                    QGraphicsItem* item= new TileGraphicsItem(thetile);
                    m_scene->addItem(item);
                }
                else if(map->getType()==twoditor::HEXAGONTILE)
                {
                    QGraphicsItem* item= new HexagonGraphicsItem(thetile);
                    m_scene->addItem(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works for a map with 100x100 Tiles. But if i want to create even larger maps..the loading time is really unbearable..
Can someone give me advice for a better representation of a tile map? Are there other convenient ways to show a map and edit cells(tiles) inside it?

EDIT: `TileGraphicItem` paint function:

```
void TileGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,QWidget *widget){

setZValue(0);

if(!m_thetile->getImage().isNull())
{
  painter->drawImage(0,0,m_thetile->getImage());
}
QPainterPath circle_path;

QRect duwagrect(boundingRect().x(),boundingRect().y(),boundingRect().width(),boundingRect().height());
circle_path.addRect(duwagrect);

m_pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
m_pen.setColor(Qt::black);
m_pen.setWidth(1);
painter->setPen(m_pen);
painter->drawPath(circle_path);

if(m_thetile->getProperty()->getBlocks())
{
    QPainterPath circle_path;
    QRect duwagrect(boundingRect().x()+2,boundingRect().y()+2,boundingRect().width()-3,boundingRect().height()-3);
    circle_path.addRect(duwagrect);
    m_pen.setStyle(Qt::DotLine);
    m_pen.setColor(Qt::red);
    m_pen.setWidth(2);
    painter->setPen(m_pen);
    painter->drawPath(circle_path);
}
if(this->isSelected())
{
  QPainterPath circle_path;
  QRect duwagrect(boundingRect().x()+2,boundingRect().y()+2,boundingRect().width()-3,boundingRect().height()-3);
  circle_path.addRect(duwagrect);
  m_pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
  m_pen.setColor(Qt::green);
  m_pen.setWidth(3);
  painter->setPen(m_pen);
  painter->drawPath(circle_path);
}

if(option->state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
{
  QPainterPath circle_path;
  QRect duwagrect(boundingRect().x()+2,boundingRect().y()+2,boundingRect().width()-3,boundingRect().height()-3);
  circle_path.addRect(duwagrect);
  m_pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
  m_pen.setColor(Qt::cyan);
  m_pen.setWidth(2);
  painter->setPen(m_pen);
  painter->drawPath(circle_path);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show us how you implement `TileGraphicsItem`?

Comment: Perhaps experiment with [ItemIndexMethod](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html#ItemIndexMethod-enum) and [bspTreeDepth](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html#bspTreeDepth-prop)

Comment: Is the issue with creating the items, or displaying them once created? If creating them, you could try using `QTimer` (probably with interval 0 to make it happen as fast as Qt event loop can do it) to create the items in small batches, to avoid freezing the GUI.

Comment: On more thing to check. `map->getAt(i,j)`, make sure that is constant time. If you use `QMap` (*O(log N)* value get), consider switching to `QHash` (*O(1)* value get).

Comment: what exactly do you want to see from the TileGraphicsItem? paint function?

Comment: and getAt(i,j) uses a std::vector< std::vector<Tile*> > m_map;

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are showing everything even things not needed.
You should create only visible items (items in some visible region).

Another faster approach is to create custom QGraphicsItem which paints hole map, and paint only visible tiles (no tiles as sub items).

Comment: Sounds like re-inventing the wheel. QGV is supposed to handle that stuff pretty well, and looking at the [40000 Chips demo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-chip.html), it can do it too.

Comment: yes i saw the 40000 chips..the main problem is that 40 000 chips does not draw any images..it only draws basic rectangles/lines

Comment: the approach to create a custom qgraphicsitem which paints the whole map seems interesting..but how would i handle hover or click events?